# How to get input from console instead of new line

Tags: input, console, sublimetext3

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> use to build Java code in Sublime Text, but when the program is waiting for an input from keyboard and I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then it adds a new line. So how to get input from console?

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/input-in-build-system/4111

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, here are 2 solutions that will work:

**[1]**

@ GitHub: **[PowerShell_Build](https://github.com/Enteleform/-SCRIPTS-/tree/master/SublimeText/PowerShell_Build)**

The PowerShell_Build template allows you to run 2 builds in parallel, one of which allows input.   You can also chain multiple commands to each build, independently of one another.   2 examples are included: Java & Python.

Here is a thread with more information:
**[[TEMPLATE] Multi-Command Builds with Input](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/template-multi-command-builds-with-input-powershell-script/18683)**

**[2]**

You can also use batch files to run parallel builds.

Here are 2 working **[Java batch scripts](https://gist.github.com/Enteleform/94dae9c3dce3a928ca96)**, one for input & one for no input.

*( This is the method I used prior to developing PowerShell_Build.  It works, but it not as versatile )*